# Evitar nomes repetidos em json

Tags: python, json, mongodb

Estou procurando uma forma/função/método para que não seja possível repetir o valor salvo no Json, por exemplo:

Estou salvando o json abaixo e não quero que de para salvar o mesmo nome no json.

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": "59a5c80dc75969297837c51e",
      "name": "uza",
      "password": "3648726"
    },
    {}
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "59a5c811c75969297837c51f",
      "name": "kuza",
      "password": "3648726"
    },
    {}
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": "59a5c83ec75969297837c520",
      "name": "kuza",
      "password": "3648726"
    },
    {}
  ]
]
```

O meu código que faz a criação do usuário no Json é este:

```
@api.route('/', methods=['POST'])
def create():

    # Pegar os dados da requisição
    user_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    if not user_json:
        return "FAIL"

    # Criar uma entidade a partir do JSON
    user, errors = schema.load(user_json)
    if bool(errors):
        return jsonify(errors)
        user.save()
    return "SUCCESS"
```

Podem me ajudar?

Comment: Embora a msg tenha sido editada pelo @Articuno, esse codigo esta muito estranho, eu pensei em editar mas fiquei com receio de alterar a intenção do autor. `create()` não é uma função? então todo o codigo abaixo do `def create()` não teria que estar identado? a penultima linha `user.save()` **nunca** será executada, é isso mesmo? Certeza que é python? Não seria o caso de editar a msg para torna-la mais clara?

Comment: desculpa, é que quando copio e colo aqui tudo fica foda da identação e eu não percebi. Vou corrigir.

Comment: Você terá que percorrer todos os registros no JSON e verificar se o nome coincide com algum já registrado. Esse JSON fica armazenado onde? Em arquivo? Como você pode obtê-lo dentro da função `create`?